# How to Bind my list to a combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

I want to fill combobox content with my list in WPF. I can do it normally in winform but wpf looks a bit different..

I dont create any code in XAML. whole controls create dynamically and at run time..

so here is my code

cmbKriterKategori is a combobox.

```
                cmbKriterKategori.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
                cmbKriterKategori.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
                cmbKriterKategori.ItemsSource = yHelper.GetCriterList().ToList();
```

an error occours

> Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

and I also tried like that

```
                cmbKriterKategori.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
                cmbKriterKategori.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
                cmbKriterKategori.DataContext = yHelper.GetCriterList().ToList();
```

it doesnt occour any error but combobox hasnt any item..

yHelper.GetCriterList().ToList(); this function returns List> 
and yHelper.GetCriterList() returns Dictionary

I used that code in winform and it works..

```
                cmbKriterKategori.DisplayMember = "Value";
                cmbKriterKategori.ValueMember ="Key";
                cmbKriterKategori.DataSource = yhelper.GetCriterList().ToList();
```

So, What is the problem?

Comment: Are you adding anything to .Items? You can't add to .Items and .ItemsSource....one or the other.....just set the .ItemsSource and you should be fine

Comment: you can do that if you use a BindingList however..

Comment: DJKRAZE and @colinsmith, I am sorry but I cant understand both of you :) what do you mean?

Comment: Can you show more of your code right from the creation of your cmbKriterJategori.....are you doing cmbKriterKategori.Items.Add(....) anywhere ?

Comment: @colinsmith, Why I must add item to combobox? I already use datacontext. It must add items automatically, musnt it ?

Comment: @DJKRAZE, I dont know how to use bindinglist with combobox.

Comment: ...use the ItemsSource and NOT the .Items "IF" you were using that....i.e. don't use both at same time ... the message "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource."...implies you have set .Items somehow.

Comment: @colinsmith, I see what you mean, but I dont use adding function to add item. I just want to use datacontext or itemssource but I get an error which I wrote above

Comment: can you show the rest of your code...thanks.

Comment: create an instance of BindingList then assign the fill the list and assign the data source of the combobox to that BindingList Variable..

Comment: @colinsmith, I really feel like an idiot ... when I created this object I added some kind of items  and I commented it and it works.. thank you really.. How can i overlook it... its so stupidly..

Comment: @DJKRAZE, Okay I solved my problem because of colinsmith.. I dont need to use bindinglist .. but Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to clear your combo items so the `Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource` exception won't be thrown

```
        cmbKriterKategori.Items.Clear();
        cmbKriterKategori.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
        cmbKriterKategori.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
        cmbKriterKategori.ItemsSource = yHelper.GetCriterList().ToList();
```

Comment: yes exactly.. I wrote many codes to try something and I forgot to remove it :) but it is really good lesson for me :)